# Bald detection using Keras

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, computer-vision, classification

I was wondering if anyone can help by providing me with some guidelines for creating a bald-or-not image classifier.

So far I have a model for face and eye detection and to sum it up, this is my main questions:

1. Where can I find datasets for this kind of classification without going to google and download thousands of images by hand?
2. What classification model (i.e. the structure of layers in the network) should be used for this?

Comment: anyone? .......

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**:
You could start by looking at some of the datasets available in Kaggle or [Tensor Flow Datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets) to see if there is anything available.

If none, you could try using an **Image scraper tool** to download images quickly compared to by hand.

**Question 2**:
Typically Image Classification model uses **Convolutional Layers** and **MaxPooling layers**. On top of the commonly used **Dense Layer** for Multi-layer Perceptron.

To get started you can study the **Tensor Flow tutorial** for **Image Classification** in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification),
which classifies whether the Image is Cat or Dog.
This example can provide you with the general idea of how to build an Image Classifier.

Hope this helps you. Thanks